# Why can't I expand Windows Storage Space due to "Specified size not valid"?

Tags: windows-10, storage-spaces

- I have created a Windows Storage Space with 3x2TB drives using Control Panel. 3 columns, thinly provisioned. PC is running Windows 10 Pro.
- I have added 1 additional 2TB drive to the Pool and extended the Space using Control Panel.
- I have filled the Space with data to the point where it complained about lack of space.
- I have added 7 additional 2TB drives to the PC, for a total of 11x2TB drives, added them to the Pool using Control Panel: [Storage Spaces showing the enlarged pool, but original Space size (which is correct).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89Ojb.png)
- I have then tried to expand the Space using Control Panel: [Storage Spaces "Change" dialog showing original values.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQCJZ.png)
- Upon entering any value (literally anything but it's current size), I'm given an error "The specified size is not valid." and the button to proceed is grayed out: [Storage Spaces "Change" dialog not allowing to make changes.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEsVp.png)
- I have then opened PowerShell and executed the command `Resize-VirtualDisk -FriendlyName DATA -Size (9TB)`, hoping to see more detailed error message. The command, however, ran successfully: [PowerShell command window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ek7B.png)
- When refreshed, the Control Panel of Storage Spaces is showing the new size of Space: [Storage Space window reporting the new correct size.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnCBZ.png)
- When I now try to resize the Space using the UI, it still reports the same error. Using PowerShell, I was able to expand the Space to 13TB without any problems.

My question is obvious: Why is the UI not letting me expand the Space, but PowerShell does?

Comment: 13.5 TB + 9 TB parity is more than 20 TB.  When you say any value what values have you tried?

Comment: Wouldn’t be shocked if this was a limitation of the UI.  Out of interest what’s the output of the same command but with -WhatIf added to it?

Comment: It makes no difference to specify what I tried, as the space is thinly provisioned. Actual pool capacity and desired volume size are not related and I could enter whatever I wanted all the way up to 65TB. You can even see in one of the screenshots "A storage space can be larger than the amount of available capacity in the storage pool." But for the clarity, I have tried to expand to 9TB, that is expanding by 1TB.

Comment: Don’t have a system with Storage Spaces so you will have to entertain intelligent dumb questions based on decades of experience  from those in that situation.

Comment: I have several questions about Storage Spaces opened and I'm trying my best to write them in most concise way possible for future generations of frustrated IT people, apologies if anything is unclear. I can't currently try to run the same command with `WhatIf` argument, as thinly provisioned Virtual-Disks cannot be shrinked and I don't want to exceed my actual pool size.